# Populate maxDate property control on Initial Load

Tags: spotfire

hello everyone, 
               I looked for a solution but was not able to find any specific to my scenario. I have a date field using which I want to create a dropdown property control. When the report loads for the first time, I would like to populate the max date selected on the dropdown and then if users want they can select other dates.
Changing date field to string and custom sorting is not an option for me.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: can you bring the data in sorted to begin with?

Comment: @scsimon, that is not an option for me. I have this dataset coming from warehouse which is not sorted.

Comment: So, you'd like to load a table with a date range set by the property control? What is the nature of the drop-down property control? Is it fixed dates, based on a expression, based on column values? You say the data come from the warehouse; via what? Database connection? SQL? Excel table?

Comment: I don't really understand the scenario here, but using a dropdown control with a large(?) dataset, you will discover that there's an upper limit to the number of values the dropdown control is capable of displaying (I think it's ~50 or ~100; some nice round number). my suspicion is that you should quickly read through the following link and then edit your question with more detail about the problem you are trying to solve rather than solving your specific approach: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Niko, I have a date field populated with end of month date(01/31, 2/28 etc) for past 2 years. Each end of month will have almost 50,0000 records. The idea here is to create a cross table with various metrics (average $ weighted average) for each date value. So, when the report loads initially, I would like to display the report for max date that is present in the dataset. And also, the report should let users pick any date present in the dataset and see report for that specific date.

Comment: For this, here is my approach: I've created a dropdown for the date field and based on that I am filtering my report with expression. Now, I would like to display the max date when users initially open the report rather than min date that is present in the dataset. 
Since, data is coming from DB table, I don't have ability to pre-sort the data based on date field.